# Why does nth-child(1) change both paragraphs instead of one

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style these two `<div>`'s by using nth-child, however, when I add the psuedo-class: `:nth-child` to my `<p>` it changes both paragraphs instead of one.

Here's my website:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

p:nth-child(1) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pl">
 <head>
  <title>Budowa strony</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="PAI 12" 
   content="Opis strony">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
   <p>•  tekst </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nth-child consider the parent container not the whole html, so you have two p that are nth-child(1)

Comment: To expand on Temani's comment, `:nth-child(1)` would look for the first `<p>` in the `<div>`. To fix your code, you should do `div:first-child > p:first-child` (feel free to replace the `:first-child` with `:nth-child(1)`, however, Afaik there is no difference).